# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table '' in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I have created two trigger, but i have the error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table '' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I have two different database, and the table a and b have some similar column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
      AFTER UPDATE ON `base1`.`a` 
      FOR EACH ROW 
      UPDATE `base2`.`b`
      SET column_c= NEW.column_c
      where id=NEW.id;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
      AFTER UPDATE ON `base2`.`b` 
      FOR EACH ROW 
      UPDATE `base1`.`a`
      SET column_b= NEW.column_b
      where id=NEW.id;
```

I tried to change one event to BEFORE, and the same error.
What should i change ?

Comment: Adopt a different approach for synchronising your DBs - triggers aren't going to work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the issue here ?
I thought the trigger can do the synchronisation.

Comment: You are attempting to generate an infinite loop - mysql don't like that..update to base1.a will trigger an update to base2.b which triggers an update to base1.a and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explain the issue for me.